# Why does mysql-connector fail to execute the "SELECT MAX(column) FROM table" statement?

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I'd simply like to perform a "SELECT MAX(column) FROM table;" via python.  The command works fine in mysql.  I'm having a problem translating it to python and mysql-connector.

Here's the code snippet:

```
statement = "SELECT MAX(" + column + ") FROM " + table
...
try:
    conn = mysqlc.connect(...)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(statement, values)   #BOOM!
    ...
```

When it runs it crashes with "ValueError: Could not process parameters" upon entering the execute function.  From searching around the net, this error suggests a syntax error in the 'statement' but I can't see it.  If I print the 'statement' just prior to execution and then copy/paste it into a mysql command, add a ';', and hit enter it works fine.

I have success with other statements, various SELECTs and INSERTs, using python's mysql-connector.  I'm just getting hung up on this MAX() function.

I am using python 2.7.18, mysql-connector-python-8.0.23, and Rhel 8.4

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-John

Comment: Are `column` and `table` just strings? And what are `values`?

Comment: Don't pass *values*.

Comment: @gribvirus74 @BrutusForcus `column` and `table` were just strings.  'values' was the problem.
removing `values` worked.  Also, `values` was not typed the way I thought.  Should have been a tuple but wasn't.  The connector code was not expecting that and raised the exception.  Ensuring `values` was a tuple also worked.  Thank you both!